# MSAccess: Can you have a Function for a WHERE Clause?

Tags: function, ms-access

I'm trying to run a query in Access, but with a function name for a where clause.  Will this work?
My query still returns all fields, even though the function does get called, and does return a valid search criteria.  It seems like it does not get applied.

```
SELECT Field1, Field2
FROM MyTable
WHERE GetWhereClause("xx", "yy");
```

The Function GetWhereClause will return something like:

```
Field1 = 'xx' AND Field3 = 'sample'
```

Answer (score 1):

No, unfortunately you can't, because booleans are not treated as first class values in SQL. What you can do is to define a function that returns 1 for true and 0 for false, say, and then do:

```
SELECT Field1, Field2
FROM MyTable
WHERE GetWhereClauseResult("xx", "yy") = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks, not sure I understand your proposed solution a 100%.  If my function returns a 1 or a 0, then how will the where clause be retrieved/applied?  Say function GetWhereClauseResult return 0, how will my filter (Field1 = 'xx') come part of the query?

Comment: @user1208908 Mick's solution is pretty elegant. All your `GetWhereClause` function has to do is just return `1` if its conditions are met. Then the main SQL query's actual `where` clause checks if the function returned `1` or not. If yes, the row is kept. If no, the row is dropped.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this if the function returns part of a SQL string.  But only if you're constructing the query in VBA:

```
strSQL = "SELECT Field1, Field2
FROM MyTable
WHERE " & GetWhereClause('xx', 'yy') & ";"
```

Comment: The VBA was actually the part that I was trying to avoid, but seems like that is the solution.  I will do it like then.